# What is the difference between net.createServer() and net.createConnection()?

Tags: node.js, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to create a simplistic TCP client and server. Conceptually, I know that a TCP socket is the same on both the client and server side (at least, this is how it is in python). However, the steps after creating a socket are different. Ie, for clients, the socket establishes a TCP connection to the server. On the server side, the socket is bound to a specific port, and waits for connections, and when it gets a req, it creates a new connected socket. (correct me if I got anything wrong, I'm new to networking).

My question is if there's any difference between the `net.Socket` and `net.Server` classes. Did node.js separate the two, and net.Server is explicitly meant for servers? Is it still possible to use `net.Socket` to make the TCP server socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between net.createServer() and net.createConnection()?

`net.createConnection()` initiates an **outbound** TCP connection to some other host or server.

`net.createServer()` sets up a server that will accept **incoming** TCP connections from other hosts or processes.

These are opposite ends of enabling a connection.

> My question is if there's any difference between the net.Socket and net.Server classes.

Yes, there's a huge difference between them as neither is a substitute for the other.  A server **listens for inbound connections**.

A client then creates a TCP socket and attempts to connect to a server that is listening for inbound connections on the port and IP address that the server is listening on.  During the connection process, the server follows the TCP handshake process to enable the creation of a TCP socket that connects the client and server.  That TCP socket is then bidirectional so either end can then send data to the other.

Nodejs uses the `net.Socket` class as the nodejs object to represent a TCP socket so when you initiate a connection from a client, you get a `net.Socket` object that represents your TCP connection to some other server.  When you are a server and someone connects to you, you get a `net.Socket` object that represents your TCP connection to the client that connected to you.  Those two objects are different ends of a TCP connection and both ends do not have to be nodejs endpoints - they can be any language or tool that can make a standard TCP connection.

> Did node.js separate the two, and net.Server is explicitly meant for servers? Is it still possible to use net.Socket to make the TCP server socket?

Yes, `net.Server` is exclusively for servers to set up a listener for inbound connections on a specific port on your host.

`net.socket` by itself cannot listen to incoming connections (you use an instance on `net.Server` for that.  It is either used to initiate a TCP connection to some server or it is created as part of of some client connecting to your server.

Comment: So if I draw a mental diagram of what is happening between one server and one client: there is a ```net.Socket``` object on the client, and a ```net.Socket``` object _and_ a ```net.Server``` object on the server. The two ```net.Socket``` objects are what the client & server use, while the ```net.Server``` object just stays open, listening to other inbound connections.

Comment: @pastacompany - Yes, that's correct.  You can think of `net.Server` as a factory for accepting inbound connections and creating the server-side `net.Socket` to complete a TCP connection and allow it to then be used to send data either way.